# React: How to update the state of an object when a user selects a value from a drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a project which has one component where a user can select if a student is Present, Absent, or Late for a class.  I'm using React for this and I have created the display with a drop-down menu that shows the options for Present, Absent, or Late.

I'm having trouble changing the student's attendance value after the user has selected if they are present or not from the drop-down menu.  Ideally, I would like the submitted results to be displayed in another tab with a list of all the students and their attendance for that day.  This is part of the code that I have:

Attendance Component:

```
class Attendance extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            students: StudentsAlphabetical,
            list: [
                {idA: "0", option: "Present"},
                {idA: "1", option: "Absent"},
                {idA: "2", option: "Late"},
            ],
            studentAttendance: {
                id: students.id,
                FirstName: students.firstName,
                LastName: students.lastName,
                Attendance: " ",
            },
        };

        // Destructuring this.state.students
        const { id, lastName, firstName } = this.state.students;
       // Getting the length of the students array
       const studentsLength = this.state.students.length;
       // Destructuring this.state.list
       const { idA, option } = this.state.list;
   };
```

changeAttendance method:

```
changeAttendance() {
    this.state.studentAttendance.map(value => (
        <tr key={value.id}>
            <td>{value.firstName}</td>
            <td>{value.lastName}</td>
            <td>{value.Attendance}</td>
        </tr>)
};
```

render method:

```
render() {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Attendance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {/*Use the map array method to go through the students array and create the table row for each student*/}
            {this.state.students.map((student =>
            <tr key={student.id}>
                <td>{student.firstName}</td>
                <td>{student.lastName}</td>
                <td> {/*Creating dropdown button that will show if student is Present, Absent or Late*/}
                    <select>
                        {this.state.list.map(item => (
                            <option key={item.idA} value={item.option}>
                                {item.option}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
        <Button color="secondary" size="lg" block onClick={this.changeAttendance}> {/*Submit button*/}
            Submit Attendance
        </Button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

I would like some advice as to how I can change the Attendance part in the studentAttendance array after the user has selected from the drop-down menu if the student was either Present, Absent or Late. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your target is something like this, try this way:

```
sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-hoover-9w31y?file=/src/App.js

import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectValue: "Absent",
      students: [
        { id: 1, name: "st1", attendance: "-" },
        { id: 2, name: "st1", attendance: "-" },
        { id: 3, name: "st1", attendance: "-" }
      ]
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e, id) => {
    let newStudents = this.state.students.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, attendance: e.target.value };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ students: newStudents });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <p>List: </p>
          {this.state.students.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>id: {item.id}</td>
                <td>name: {item.name}</td>
                <td>
                  attendance:{" "}
                  <span>
                    <select
                      value={item.attendance}
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, item.id)}
                    >
                      <option value="Present">Present</option>
                      <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
                      <option value="Late">Late</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will let you know if this works.